# Animated webpage for displaying the navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have created webpage its displaying the path like

> Gmail->sign in->username-> password

I want display in the webpage by using animation like first it will display

> gmail->(afterwards it should display )-> sign in as follows .

Is this is possible?

Comment: What did u try so far? :)

Comment: I have created that navigation through <h1>Gmail->signin->username</h1> I want to animated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Could try out

animate.css - https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

ScrollMagic - http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/

or you can write your own keyframes or create at [CSS-Animate](http://www.cssanimate.com/)

(You can customize either of this with js for onclick events if you like)

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 animations:

create keyframes animate - http://cssanimate.com/

Keyframes - http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Others - http://www.creativebloq.com/css3/animation-with-css3-712437

Others - http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/transitions-animations/